# Iterating through object properties in IList without a loop

Tags: c#, ilist

Consider the following situation:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name {get; set}
    public string Email {get; set}
}

public class EnployeeGroup
{
    //List of employees in marketting
    public IList<Employee> MarkettingEmployees{ get; }

    //List of employees in sales
    public IList<Employee> SalesEmployees{ get; }
}

private EnployeeGroup GroupA;

int MarkettingCount;
string MarkettingNames;

MarkettingCount = GroupA.MarkettingEmployees.Count; //assigns MarkettingCount=5, this will always be 5-10 employees
MarkettingNames = <**how can i join all the GroupA.MarkettingEmployees.Name into a comma separated string?** >

//I tried a loop:
foreach(Employee MktEmployee in GroupA.MarkettingEmployees)
{
    MarkettingNames += MktEmployee.Name + ", ";
}
```

The loop works, but i want to know:

1. Is Looping the most efficient/elegant way of doing this? If not then what are the better alternatives? I tried string.join but couldnt get it working..
2. I want to avoid Linq..

Comment: And why would you want to avoid LINQ exactly?

Comment: Although i'd love to know how to do this in Linq, but i am curious to know if there is way to achieve this without Linq

Comment: Well I would say the better alternative is LINQ.... but

Comment: @user3006467 You don't want to use a loop and you don't want to use Linq? Both restrictions seem totally arbitrary.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Homework is often arbitrary.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You're asking for an opinion (what is better, what is more elegant) rather than a technical solution (I tried something to make it better, but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?).

Comment: @Mark This isn't homework, it may look so because i simplified the code.

Comment: @Mark This is definitely programming question, i have a problem, i tried solution 1,2.. want to know if there is an alternative/better way? That's how we learn.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a little bit of LINQ whether you like it or not ;)

```
MarkettingNames = string.Join(", ", GroupA.MarkettingEmployees.Select(e => e.Name));
```

Comment: +1 because your edit made me laugh (and your answer is 100% correct).

Comment: I am fairly new to LINQ, so How does this LINQ solution compare with the loop in terms of efficiency, elegance, performance, readability etc?

Comment: LINQ in general is not faster than loops since it uses them also (implicitly). But the `string.Join` is very efficient (all the more with a list or array) and `Enumerable.Select` just projects the `Employee.Name`. So in my opinion this  approach is efficient, concise, elegant and most important: readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

From a practicality standpoint, there's no reasonable argument for avoiding a loop. Iterations are at the hard of *every* general-purpose programming language.

Using LINQ is elegant in simple cases. Again, there's no sound reason to avoid it per se.

In case you are looking for a rather obscure, academic solution, there's always [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion). However, your data structure would have to be adapted for it. Note that even if you use it, a smart compiler will detect it and optimize into a loop. The odds are agains you!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use a StringBuilder with Append instead of creating a new string at each iteration

Answer (score 0):

This would be much more efficient (see caveat below):

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Employee MktEmployee in GroupA.MarkettingEmployees)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(MktEmployee.Name + ", ");
}
```

Then this:

```
foreach(Employee MktEmployee in GroupA.MarkettingEmployees)
{
    MarkettingNames += MktEmployee.Name + ", ";
}
```

**Edit: If you were to have a large amount of employees this *would* be much more efficient. However, a trivial loop of 5-10 is actually *slightly* less efficient.**

**In small cases - this isn't going to be that large of a hit on performance, but in large cases the pay off will be significant.**

Also, if you are to use the explicit loop approach, it's probably best to trim off that last `", "` by using something like:

```
myString = myString.Trim().TrimEnd(',');
```

The article below explains when you should use `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings.

In short, in the approach you use: the concatenation is creating a new string each time, which obviously eats up a lot of memory. You also need to copy all the data from the existing string of `MarkettingNames` to the new string being appended yet another `MktEmployee.Name + ", "`.

Thank you, Jon Skeet: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: Does the StringBuilder still make sense if my loop iterates only 5-10 times?